# Condition to bound the decay rate of an exponentially stable linear system using Lyapunov stability theory?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions, lyapunov-exponents

Could someone elaborate or provide additional justification for a bound on the decay rate of an exponentially stable system?  The following comes from Boyd, El Ghaoui, Feron, and Balakrishan's book, "Linear Matrix Inequalities in System and Control theory" on page 66:

[image: description of exponential decay]

For reference, the definition of LDI (5.1) is found on page 61:

[image: description of an LDI]

If $dV(x)/dt \leq -2\alpha V(x)$, then why does $V(x(t)) \leq V(x(0))e^{-2\alpha t}$?  I know that from basic Lyapunov theory, $V(x(t))=V(x(0)) + \int_0^t \dot{V}(x(\tau))d\tau\leq V(x(0))$ since $\dot{V}(x(t))\leq 0$.  The above has the extra exponential that I don't know how to derive.  Second, if $V(x(t)) \leq V(x(0))e^{-2\alpha t}$, then why does $\|x(t)\|\leq e^{-\alpha t}\kappa(P)^{1/2}\|x(0)\|$?

Comment: The first statement is simply from the fact that $\frac{d ln(V)}{dt} < -2\alpha $ (given that $V>0$), then $V(x(t)) < V(x(0))e^{-2\alpha t}$. How is $\kappa(P)$ defined? Is it the positive square root of a positive definite matrix?

Comment: Ok, cool.  The first part took me a moment, but for anyone else $\log(V(x(t)))=\log(V(x(0)))+\int_0^t \dot{\log(V(x(t)))} d\tau\leq\log(V(x(0))-2\alpha t=\log(V(x(0))e^{-2\alpha t})$,
which implies $V(x(t))\leq V(x(0))e^{-2\alpha t}$ since the natural log is monotonically increasing.  Thanks for that.  As far as $\kappa(P)$, it's the condition number, so the ratio of the largest and smallest singular values, $\kappa(P)=\sigma_{\max}(P)/\sigma_{\min}(P)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mastrok helped bring me to the final solution.

Let $J(t)=\log(V(x(t))$.  Then, we have that

$$
J^\prime(t) = \frac{1}{V(x(t))} V^\prime(x(t)) x^\prime(t)\leq \frac{1}{V(x(t)} (-2\alpha V(x(t))) = -2\alpha
$$

Next, we have that

$$\begin{align}
\log(V(x(t)))&=\log(V(x(0)))+\int_0^t J^\prime(t) d\tau\\
&\leq\log(V(x(0)))-\int_0^t 2\alpha\\
&=\log(V(x(0)))- 2\alpha t\\
&= \log(V(x(0))e^{-2\alpha t})
\end{align}$$

This implies $V(x(t))\leq V(x(0))e^{-2\alpha t}$ since $\log$ is monotonically increasing and this answers part one of my question above.

For part 2, note that

$$\begin{align}
&&\lambda_{\min}(P)\|x(t)\|^2
&\leq x(t)^T P x(t)\\
&&&\leq x(0)^T P x(0) e^{-2\alpha t}\\
&&&\leq \|x(0)\|^2 \lambda_{\max}(P) e^{-2\alpha t}\\
\Longrightarrow
&&\|x(t)\|^2
&\leq \frac{\lambda_{\max}(P)}{\lambda_{\min}(P)}\|x(0)\|^2e^{-2\alpha t}\\
\Longrightarrow
&&\|x(t)\|
&\leq \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_{\max}(P)}{\lambda_{\min}(P)}}\|x(0)\|e^{-\alpha t}\\
&&&=\kappa(P)^{1/2}\|x(0)\|e^{-\alpha t}
\end{align}$$